# Injecting jQuery into Google.com using a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension and would quite like to inject jQuery into the Google website, but for some reason it just isn't working for me.

Here is my manifest file with the `content_scripts`:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["*://www.google.com/*"],
    "css": ["src/inject/inject.css"],
    "js": ["js/jquery/jquery.min.js", "src/inject/inject.js"],
    "run_at" : "document_start"
  }]
```

and jQuery is in the folder it is supposed to be. In my `inject.js` file I have:

```
$("body").append("Hello World");
console.log("Loaded.");
```

And strangely enough when I go to Google.com, `Loaded.` does appear in the console, but `Hello World` does not get appended to the `body`, nor do I get an error in the console which is very strange. I even did inside of `inject.js`:

```
if (window.jQuery) {  
    $("body").append("Hello World");
    console.log("Loaded.");
} else {
    console.log('Not Loaded.');
}
```

and `Loaded.` appeared in the console again, and `Hello World` did not get appened... I don't know what the problem is... It doesn't seem to make sense.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Probably either the `$` variable, or your appended element, or both, is being overwritten by Google's code.

Comment: I'm not sure you need the `run_at` part, as you probably want to wait for the page to mostly load before you act on it, right? Is your text being added to the page and then hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

content scripts run in sandboxed contexts. So you cannot change the page-dom from within them. But there is a workaround:

in your content-script, you add all your scripts via script-tags like this:

```
var script_tag = document.createElement("script");
script_tag.setAttribute("src", chrome.extension.getURL("js/jquery/jquery.min.js"));

document.head.appendChild(script_tag);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did try that implementation but I keep getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null` on the `document.head.appendChild(script_tag);` line... Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, never mind, I got it. It appears `"run_at"` needs to be set at `document_end`.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Content scripts are exactly for interacting with the page DOM. They are only isolated from the *javascript* variables and functions of the webpage.

Comment: In Chrome console I get this error `Refused to load the script 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com".| (anonymous) @ VM435:4
<script src=​"http:​/​/​code.jquery.com/​jquery-1.9.1.min.js">​</script>​`. Suggestions? Thanks